# Importing / Exporting data with Dataverse (CDS)

Tags: azure-sql-database, dynamics-crm, common-data-service, onpremises-gateway, dataverse

I'm looking into using the dataverse (CDS).
I have an on prem sql server and a server hosted on azure which is also on prem.
I want to know if it is possible to

1. Export data from dataverse into an on prem sql server
2. Import data from an on prem sql server into dataverse
3. Is it possible to continuously pull data from an on premise sql database into the dataverse
4. Use data from D365 into dataverse and vice versa?

I have looked into Microsofts Data Integrator but this isn't an option that would work.

If it is possible how would I go about doing this and is there any limitations that I need to consider?

For instance if this is possible with custom connectors will there be performance issues that need to be considered ?

Thanks

Comment: i would just use powerautomate flow if the logic gets heavy move it to Logic Apps in Azure, - all your required connector are available

Answer (score 0):

You can use [dataflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/dataflows/overview-dataflows-across-power-platform-dynamics-365) from Microsoft. Using dataflow you can upsert the data, meaning create new records and update existing records. However, dataflow will delete the data from the destination that it does not find in the source.